# Socket programming- connecting several servers together

Tags: java, sockets, nio, serversocket

For a project for Uni, we are building a very simple and basic distributed data-storage. So we started with a basic client-server connection which worked just fine. 
The next part of the project is to connect several servers together so that (in the end) each server will be responsible for a different range of the stored data.

I have written a very small method that creates a new socket for between the server and every other server. We were instructed to give the servers time to start before trying to connect to them. 
But the method keeps throwing `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)`.

```java
static void connectToOtherServers(int myPort) {

    for (int i = 0; i < ports.length; i++) {
        boolean isConnected = false;

        while (!isConnected) {
            try {
                if (myPort != ports[i]) {
                    Socket socket = new Socket(addresses[i], ports[i]);
                    sockets.add(socket);
                    isConnected = true;
                }
                else if (myPort == ports[i]) {
                    isConnected = true;
                }
            } catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    System.out.println("sleeping");
                } catch(Exception e2) {
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the constructor of the class has already a listening socket for incoming connections.

```java
public App (int port) throws IOException {
    selector = Selector.open();
    heineStore = new HeineStore();

    // Setup server socket for listening
    serverSocket = ServerSocketChannel.open();
    serverSocket.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));
    serverSocket.configureBlocking(false);

    // Register acceptor for OP_ACCEPT events
    SelectionKey key = serverSocket.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
    key.attach(new Acceptor(heineStore));
}
```

Hope any of you guys have suggestions on how to solve this problem.

EDIT: I tried connecting a client to the first server and then starting all other servers (3 other servers), they all connected to the first server (that established a connection with a client) but then they are stuck in the loop while trying to connect to each other.
One of the requirements for the project though, is that the servers are first established a connection to one another and only then connect to a client.

Comment: How are the arrays `addresses` and `ports` populated? How do you know there are servers listening on those endpoints?

Comment: @James K Polk So `addresses` and `ports` are populated in a different method that reads from a config-file the IP-addresses and ports of the other servers, they are basically all using `127.0.0.1` and some port. I double-checked it several times and it works fine. 
The servers are listening because of `serverSocket = ServerSocketChannel.open();` aren't they?

Comment: So all the servers you are trying to connect to were launched with your `App` class by you? This is confusing.

Comment: yes... Each server is just a new instance of that class (`App`), I just start them in a new Terminal with another port as one of the variables.

Comment: They are listening but they actually have to call `accept()` in order for the sockets to be connected. Perhaps that is happening in `HeineStore` but it isn't visible in your code so we can't help debug it.